# Webpack 5 cannot import UMD module

Tags: javascript, webpack, umd

I recently upgraded to Webpack 5 and I'm having some trouble importing UMD modules.

In particular, I'm trying to import Leaflet. Leaflet seems to export a UMD module created by rollup.js, which looks like this:

```js
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
  (factory((global.L = {})));
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
  [...]
})));
```

As you can see, it first tries to use CommonJS (if `exports` and `module` is defined), then it tries to use AMD (if `define` is defined), and otherwise it tries to put itself to the global scope by referencing `this` from the module context.

Webpack (without any loaders) compiles it to this:

```js
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && "object" !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
  typeof define === 'function' && __webpack_require__.amdO ? define(['exports'], factory) :
  (factory((global.L = {})));
}(undefined, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
  [...]
})));
```

Concretely, what it did was:

- Replace `typeof module` with `"object"`
- Replace `define.amd` with `__webpack_require__.amd0`
- Replace `this` with `undefined`

During the build, webpack gives me a warning: `export 'default' (imported as 'L') was not found in 'leaflet' (possible exports: )`. When I open the compiled bundle in the browser, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'L' of undefined`.

What happens is that CommonJS fails (because `exports` is not defined), AMD fails (because `define` is not defined) and finally setting the global also fails because `this` is replaced with `undefined`.

According to [the Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/), Webpack should universally support importing CommonJS and AMD modules, but it seems in this case neither of the two work.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I narrowed the problem down and discovered that the problem was caused by the fact that I was using an `imports-loader` in a certain way.

Before the update, I used an `imports-loader` to add any needed transitive dependencies that my dependencies were not importing, in particular CSS files. The configuration looked something like this:

```js
{ module: { rules: [ {
    test: /\/node_modules\/leaflet\/.*\.js$/,
    loader: "imports-loader?asdf=leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
} ] } }
```

After the upgrade, webpack didn't accept the string syntax for loaders anymore, and imports-loader also changed its syntax, so I changed it to:

```js
{ module: { rules: [ {
    test: /\/node_modules\/leaflet\/.*\.js$/,
    loader: "imports-loader",
    options: {
        imports: "default leaflet/dist/leaflet.css asdf"
    }
} ] } }
```

This seemed to do the job and properly included the necessary CSS file. However, when I discovered that this part of the config is the cause of the problem, I dug deeper into the [documentation of `imports-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/#syntax). It turns out the configuration I was using was now generating the following line of code:

```js
import asdf from "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

(and I could have used `"side-effects leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"` to get the same result without having to use `asdf` as a bogus import name). While this properly imported the CSS file, it probably caused webpack to think that this file is a proper ES module, disabling support for CommonJS/AMD/UMD modules. I changed the configuration of imports-loader to the following:

```js
{ module: { rules: [ {
    test: /\/node_modules\/leaflet\/.*\.js$/,
    loader: "imports-loader",
    options: {
        imports: "pure leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
        type: "commonjs"
    }
} ] } }
```

According to the docs, this creates the following code line:

```js
require("leaflet/dist/leaflet.css");
```

After making this change, it seems to work without problems.

Interestingly, it seems that webpack actually detects the whole UMD block rather than just providing the `exports` and `define` variables, so it compiles the Leaflet code into this now:

```js
(function (global, factory) {
   true ? factory(exports) :
  0;
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
   [...]
})));
```